# Prevent Mule from adding default content type

Tags: http, mule, content-type

How do I prevent Mule from adding a default content-type to HTTP responses?

Currently, Mule is adding 'text/plain' content-type. I have REST calls that don't always specify the expected content, and services that don't indicate the served content - leaving it to the client (browser) to interpret.

My "proxy" flow looks like this:

```
    <flow name="DragonScalaProxy" doc:name="DragonScalaProxy">
  <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8002" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP" disableTransportTransformer="true"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <copy-properties propertyName="http.method" doc:name="Copy HTTP Method"/>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
        <delete-message-property key="Content-Type"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
  <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8000#[header:INBOUND:http.request]" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP" disableTransportTransformer="true"/>
    <remove-property propertyName="Content-Type" doc:name="Remove Content-Type"/>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
        <delete-message-property key="Content-Type"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transformer to set it to whatever you want.
Eg like so for a xml type:

```
<message-properties-transformer name="contentTypeTextXML">
   <add-message-property key="Content-Type" value="text/xml" />
</message-properties-transformer>
```

or you can delete it with the **delete-message-property** processor

Comment: Just copied my flow into my post. I have spinkled some message/property deletion transformers through the flow. This is not how i want it, as, if the server does want to set a content-type it must be able to. Still, this does not remove the text/plain content-type from the response.

Comment: @Gilbert its very unusual to not have a content type though

Comment: Yes, I'm beginning to think I'm going about this wrong - and possibly my noob coming out. The non-content type is static content (html pages, images etc.) - perhaps I should be setting this up more like a web server - with Ajax end-point, like in the first Mule demo. Gonna try a few things...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem; whenever I would transform the payload of a Mule message to be JSON, the Mule runtime would automatically set the MIME type of the Mule message to be *application/json*.  When the *http:request* component saw a MIME type of *application/json*, it would then set the ***content-type*** of the HTTP request to be *application/json*, as well.  Unfortunately, the RESTful service that I needed to call only recognized a ***content-type*** of *text/x-json*. While the MIME type of the Mule message was set to *application/json*, I was unable to manually override the ***content-type*** used by *http:request*; it simply ignored the *http:header* setting for ***content-type***.  I solved this dilemma by adding an *expression-component* to override the MIME type set within the Mule message's *SimpleDataType*, and then I was finally able to successfully override  the ***content-type*** within the *http:request* component to be the type that I needed, like so:

```
    ...
        <expression-component doc:name="Override default DataType"><!CDATA[
          message.getDataType().setMimeType('*/*');
        ]]></expression-component>

        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="search.do" method="POST" doc:name="Call RESTful service to perform search">
          <http:request-builder>
            ...
            <http:header headerName="content-type" value="text/x-json"/>
            ...
          </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>
    ...
```